# connecting two 3.7v battery's to tablet, in parallel for extend the working capa

Tags: power-supply, voltage

my tablet have 2500mah battery. it works for four hour. but I want to extend the source power.
so I want to connect another same voltage battery to tablet. battery was 1500mah.
can i make connection in parallel, and how much it is safe.

Comment: It is never considered safe to arbitrarily parallel batteries unless they are identical types. Even then there can be issues with them sharing the load equally and charging properly.

Comment: Wiring batteries in parallel, different mAh's, same voltage... How is this more suited for Superuser, instead of electronics & electrical engineering?

Answer (score 1):

You would be far better off getting yourself a suitably sized power bank product that can operate your tablet whilest connected to the power bank. The power bank would connect to the tablet with the normal USB charging plug.

Trying to modify the tablet itself is a chancy proposition. There is a good possibility that the charger built into the tablet may be unable to safely stand up to two paralleled batteries even if you could somehow manage to select the proper type of battery, get it to fit and get it wired in properly.

The advantage of the power bank approach is there is no need to open up the tablet and mess around with its internal wiring. Also the prepackaged unit will be safer to use. Another advantage is that if you need longer time support you can acquire multiple power banks and swap them in as needed. The power bank can also be used with multiple products including the your mobile phone.

You can find power bank products at many online retail sites such as eBay and Amazon.

Comment: +1. Also that third (or forth pin) on phone or tablet batteries is used for either temperature sensing or even a data connection, so you can't just parallel wire another battery (on top of the problems Michael mentioned in his comment).